# getting Pure test from html text using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am using struts, and I am getting html text from database and I am storing it in a string and passing it to jsp. Now in jsp I have to extract pure text from that html string and has to display in the TextArea using javascript.

Please suggest some solutions, I am not allowed to use jquery.

Comment: Can you provide what the string that is passed in looks like?

Comment: It could be any html text...

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like a mini-parser. 
Like this function:

```
    function HTMLtoBB(html) {
    search = new Array( /\<b\>(.*?)\<\/b\>/g,
                        /\<i\>(.*?)\<\/i\>/g,
                        /\<u\>(.*?)\<\/u\>/g,
                        /\<font size=\'(.*?)\'\>(.*?)\<\/font\>/g,
                        /\<font color=\'(.*?)\'\>(.*?)\<\/font\>/g,
                        /\<img src=\'(.*?)\'\>/g,
                        /\<a href=\'(.*?)\'\>(.*?)\<\/a\>/g,
                        /\<blockqoute\>(.*?)\<\/blockquote\>/g,
                        /\<center\>(.*?)\<\/center\>/g
                      );

    replace = new Array("[b]$1[/b]",
                        "[i]$1[/i]",
                        "[u]$1[/u]",
                        "[size=$1]$2[/size]",
                        "[color=$1]$2[/color]",
                        "[img=$1]",
                        "[url=$1]$2[/url]",
                        "[quote]$1[/quote]",
                        "[center]$1[/center]"
                       );

    for (i = 0; i < search.length; i++) {
        html = html.replace(search[i], replace[i]);
    }

    return html;
}
```

This will convert the HTML-Tags to BB-Codes. Or you replace the BB-Codes with something other.

Answer (score 0):

You could attach the loaded HTML to the dom, and then use `element.innerText` to strip away all the HTML, leaving just the plain text (if this is what you want to do - I don't think it is completely clear from your question)